# Не работает AJAX c Django

Tags: django, ajax

Есть сайт на Джанго, где при нажатии на кнопку - товар добавляется в корзину (работает через сессии. Сейчас работает, обновляя каждый раз страницу. Хочу написать AJAX, чтобы не перезагружался постоянно. Однако, возникла проблема, что при нажатии на кнопку - товар добавляется, но и заместо страницы выводится белая страница с ответом в формате json. Как понимаю, то AJAX скрипт не взаимодействует с представлением Джанго. Изрыл весь интернет, ChatGPT тоже не помог (впервые сталкиваюсь с AJAX). Помогите исправить. Вот код:

views.py

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=1)
    cart.add(product=product)
    return JsonResponse({'success': True})
```

base.html

```
<form action="{% url 'add_cart' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="ДОБАВИТЬ В КОРЗИНУ" class="itm-btn" id="cartBtnId">
</form>

$('#cartBtnId').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type:form.attr('method'),
        url:form.attr('action'),
        data:form.serialize(),
        success:function(response) {
            if (data.status === 'success') {
                console.log('123'); 
            } else {
                alert('Error!');
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error!');
               }            
            });
        });
```

Comment: В вашем коде `form` это не форма, а кнопка

Comment: @andreymal так должна же быть кнопка, нет? типа после нажатия - срабатывает ajax? как исправить можно?

Comment: И вы пытаетесь вытащить из этой кнопки какие-то method, action и serialize, которых в кнопках никогда не существовало. «как исправить можно?» — на например всё-таки взять вместо кнопки форму откуда-нибудь

Comment: Ну и, хотя вы этого не осознаёте, вы на самом деле хотите обработать не нажатие кнопки, а отправку формы (не забывайте, что форму можно отправить не только кнопкой, но и нажатием Enter на клавиатуре например), а значит лучше взять https://learn.javascript.ru/forms-submit